# Error Installing 'pod Firebase/Firestore' in my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

I am unable to install pod Firebase/Firestore. I am also unable to locate the error also, here is all the information:

**Version information:**

```
   CocoaPods : 1.10.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
    RubyGems : 2.5.2.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G103)
       Xcode : 11.0 (11A420a)
         Git : git version 2.21.0 (Apple Git-122)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

**My PodFile:**

[image]

At the end of terminal it provides following information:

[image]

At the start of terminal, where I give "pod install" command:

[image]

Inside terminal, where the error occurred:

[image]

I had installed it a couple of times earlier, but this time it is giving this strange behaviour which I am unable to figure out. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT: @Jay**

So at first I removed all cocoapods versions by 'sudo gem uninstall cocoapods' and then installed cocoapods again, here it is:

[image]

Then, I copied pods from a working project and created a new project and in the podfile pasted those pods, here:

[image]

Then after executing pod install, I got the same error, here:

[image]

I don't know why is this happening, and is driving me crazy to know that it is not an issue from firebase. I am unable to figure out exactly what is happening.

Comment: Might be a corrupted character, like an invalid single quote character in the Podfile

Comment: I've copied them directly from available pods on the firebase google page. Carefully checked the podfile, and found no problem. Still not figuring out what is the problem..

Comment: Do you think that this could be a backend firestore fault ??

Comment: Might be that single quotes don't copy correctly from a web page to the text editor. What is the link? It would be better to share the actual contents of the Podfile in your question instead of a screen shot.

Comment: # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'PodTest' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for PodTest
  
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

end

Comment: @PaulBeusterien this is the exact copy/paste of my pod file of newly created project, here on this site it is trimming the new lines, but as you may see, the single quotes are all looking well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after some struggle I got the solution to my problem. My pod repo was somewhat outdated and because of that I was unable to install the pod. The error in the terminal was reading something like 'Unexpected token by boringSSL...'

I performed the following commands to remove my pod repository and reinstalled it, after which the pod installed correctly:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove the cocoapods setup from your project using

   `pod deintegrate`
2. Remove Podfile, Podfile.lock and project.xcworkspace files from the project directory.
3. Use these commands one by one

   `gem list --local | grep cocoapods`

   `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

   `sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods`

   `sudo gem install cocoapods`

   `cd (PROJECT DIRECTORY)`

   `pod init`

   `pod install`

I don't know the issue but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add source in your podfile? Just an idea

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
...
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
...
```

Comment: Haven't tried, but did this now and in the terminal it said 'Cloning spec repo `cocoapods` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` and kept on like forever waiting. No progress so far..

Comment: This command trigger checkout all specs repo, so it can take some time. Also if problem still there, try to completely reinstall cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

That podfile looks a bit incomplete. It should be more like this - this is from a working project that includes Analytics, Auth and Firestore

```
project 'your_project_name.xcodeproj'

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'your_project_name' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for iOS Firestore
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
end
```

You should also update all your cocoapods

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

You may have conflicing characters in your podfile. As a quick test, try opening your podfile with [Cocoapods.app](https://cocoapods.org/app). Don't install, just try to open it and see if there are any errors. Save it. Then try `pod install` on the command line.

Last thing, try deintegrating your existing podfile from the project.

```
pod deintegrate
```

and then

```
pod install
```

making sure you've quit Xcode before doing the above.

Comment: I've tried again by adding the first line i.e. project 'my_project_name.xcodeproj' and copied the pods here in your file, but still it is giving the same result. If I don't add 'Firebase/firestore' the pods gets successfully installed, Only the firestore pod in not being installed. We have similar pod files. And I even have another working project which is working fine with similar pods.

Comment: @AmaisSheikh Hmm. I just built a new project using that podfile and it worked correctly. Did you do the `sudo gem install` part? Did you see it  update your pods? Were you quit out of XCode when you did `pod install`? Also, did you verify you're logged into your Developer account (XCode->Preferences->Accounts)? On that note, did you log into your developer account on apple.com and accept the most receive terms? I really don't think this is a Firebase issue; it appears to be a cocoapods or account related issue instead. You may also want to try `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` and then reinstall.

Comment: I followed your instructions, I was quit out on Xcode when I did `pod install`. And also I don't have a developer account yet, and I had used them earlier without having developer account. I have edited the question with new screen shots following your steps. Please check...

Comment: @AmaisSheikh Your pod still doesn't match mine - but more importantly, are you developing for iOS 9? Also the developer thing - there was a change recently that required a [developer account](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/). It's unrelated but something to be aware of in XCode. I added some additional things to try in my answer - be sure to fix your podfile so the format matches mine and update the iOS Version.

Comment: Thanks alot Jay for your help. It was very grateful, but unfortunately I followed every step told by you, uninstalled cocoapods and reinstalled many times, exactly copying your podfile and coping other working projects podfiles, and nothing worked after trying everything. I found a solution and I am updating the answer for future viewers.